# Does importing all in JavaScript affect performance

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am working on a testing project with the following structure:

```
project  
│
└─── jrns
│   │   journeys_1.js
│   │   journeys_2.js
|   |   Journeys.js
│   
└─── Test Suites
    │   suite1.js
    │   suite2.js
```

Each journeys_x file contains some user journeys written as functions, and the whole purpose of the Journeys file is to act as a hub of all the journeys. Journeys.js looks something like this:

```js
import {journey_1_1,
        journey_1_2} from './journeys_1';
export {journey_1_1,
        journey_1_2};

import {journey_2_1,
        journey_2_2} from './journeys_2';
export {journey_2_1,
        journey_2_2};
```

The purpose of creating that hub is to make importing easier in the test suites:

```js
import * as jrns from '../jrns/Journeys';

jrns.journey_1_2();
```

My question is the following, does importing everything this way in the test suites files affect performance since not all journeys are actually utilized within every test suite file? Also, if in journeys_1.js for example I needed to access a journey stored in journey_2 for example, would accessing it through the same importing mechanism

```js
import * as jrns from './Journeys';

jrns.journey_2_2();
```

affect performance?

Comment: don't know, does it? have you tried to see how **your** code performance is changed? Since  you've posted no *actual* code, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: The problem is that I created that structure myself, and had no opportunity to test any other structure. I am just curious if removing that hub and importing only needed journeys would improve the performance because if that is the case, I would try to shift the whole project.

Comment: well, you haven't shown any actual code - so, the pineapple is still the best answer

Comment: Yes, every file that gets imported affects performance in one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Performance can have a number of dimensions, i.e. runtime performance, memory complexity, etc. For this sort of thing you might be able to benchmark it but it might only have meaningful impact at some scale. In this case, without knowing the number of imports, it's likely impossible to say that it will have a meaningful affect. Any additional import does cost some runtime or memory space, sure, but as to whether that matters is another question.

To get you to an answer on whether this matters, you could consider whether the project is at scale (some thousands of tests to be run), how frequently this test suite is run (on commit, on PR, etc), and whether it's run on local machines vs a cloud-based CI system. If your project is not at scale and may not be for a long time, or if it is infrequently run, or if it's run in a CI system, the minor difference in runtime performance probably does not have an observable/meaningful effect.